# Variable inside curly brackets

Tags: php

I know how to execute php variable inside quotes

```
$q1 = 1;
$q2 = 2;
$q3 = 3;
$q4 = 4;
$q5 = 5;

echo "${q1}"; //outputs 1
```

How can i output them in a loop?

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
{
    echo "${q$i}"; //how to make $i work here?
}
```

How to make `$i` work along with `$q`?

**UPDATE**

i want the quotes to be there, because i am creating a string in a loop and i want to pass that loop to mysql query. So i want the string to be like

```
$str = '$q1, $q2, $q3';
```

and when i pass it to mysql query it should interpret the values of $q1, $q2, $q3 which is 1,2,3

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ($str)");
```

So it should become

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1,2,3)");
```

It is just an example i know the syntax of `mysql_query` is wrong but you know

Comment: From what I know, the syntax I've always used is {$q}.  I don't know about variable variables though.  I've never liked them and considered them bad style and have always used arrays instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
<?php

$arr = array();

$q1 = 1;
$q2 = 2;
$q3 = 3;
$q4 = 4;
$q5 = 5;

for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
{
    $arr[] = ${"q".$i}; 
}

$str = implode($arr, ',');

print_r($str);
```

Outputs:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

In action: http://codepad.org/ep7sraT5

Comment: It should output the values inside those variables

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
{
    echo ${"q".$i};
}
```

Output:

```
12345
```

Codepad: http://codepad.org/2PIshh41

**UPDATE:**

Since you wanted to store the value in varible, you can do this:

```
$str = '';
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
{
    $str .= "${"q".$i}, "; 
}
$str = rtrim($str, ' ,'); //trim last comma

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ($str)"); 

//becomes mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want the quotes to be there, something like `echo "${"q"."$i"}";`

Comment: Yes there is reason. I am actually making a string in a loop and i want to echo all of the string at the end `echo $str` where str should be like `${q1}, $q{2} .....`

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
{
    $x = "q$i";
    echo $$x;
}
```

[works!](http://ideone.com/sNp6PB)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it should work :)

```
echo ${"q${i}"};
```

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes around the whole thing are useless

use

```
echo ${'q' . $i};
```

EDIT: If you want to create the comma seperated string, why not try

```
$q1 = 1;
$q2 = 2;
$q3 = 3;
$q4 = 4;
$q5 = 5;

$parts = array();
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
{
    $parts[] = ${'q' . $i};
}

$str = implode(', ', $parts);
```

Also consider escaping the values before running the MYSQL, you could do this within the for loop before adding the value to the `$parts` array